# Changing line spacing in Leaflet Popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

simple question here: the spacing on my leaflet map popup seems to be stuck in double space. I'm trying to get each new line to appear like so:

```
 Name: xxx
 Date: xxx
```

Instead of how it currently is:

```
Name: xxx

Date: xxx
```

Here's my script:

```
function createPopup(properties, attribute, layer, radius){
//add city to popup content string
var popupContent = '<h3>' + "Name: " + properties.info_firstName + " " + properties.info_lastName + '</h3>';
//add formatted attribute to panel content 

popupContent += "<p><b>Number of Installs:</b> " + properties.GE_Count + "</p>" + "<p><b>Number of Installs:</b> " + properties.GE_Count + "</p>";


//replace the layer popup
layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {
    offset: new L.Point(0,-radius)
});
};
```

And my CSS:

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    opacity: .8;
}

.leaflet-popup-tip {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    opacity: .8;
}

.leaflet-popup-content p, h3{
    color: #191900;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 12px
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

to your CSS?

Comment: In order to target just the headers inside leaflet popups, the rule should rather look like `.leaflet-popup h3 {…}`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a simple matter of HTML.

Since you use paragraphs (`<p>` tags) for each line, you automatically get the default `p` styling, with top and bottom margin.

A simple workaround would be to get rid of the `<p>` tags and use a line break `<br />` instead.

Same for your `h3` title.

You could also specify `margin: 0` on your `p` and `h3`, since you seem to already have a CSS rule on them.